# How can I add the short acronym for the foreign language translation in acro?

Tags: acronyms, acro

In the `acro` package, I can add a `foreign` translation of the long form via `foreign` like this:

```
\DeclareAcronym{dsgvo}{
    short = DSGVO,
    long = {Datenschutzgrundverordnung}
    foreign = \enquote{General Data Protection Regulation},
    foreign-lang = english
}
```

This results in a "glossary" entry like this:

> **DSGVO** Datenschutz-Grundverordnung („General Data Protection Regulation“), S. 4

However, I'd also like to add the abbrevation, i.e. the acronym, for the (English) translation, i.e. I want to do something like this:

```
\DeclareAcronym{dsgvo}{
    short = DSGVO,
    long = {Datenschutz-Grundverordnung},
    foreign = \enquote{General Data Protection Regulation},
    foreign-short = GDPR, % new line
    foreign-lang = english,
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

In the end, I want an entry like this:

> **DSGVO** Datenschutz-Grundverordnung („General Data Protection Regulation“, GDPR), S. 4

The same way it may be mentioned in the inline entry.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to use that?

Comment: @LokiRagnarok depends on what you mean with "use". I'll add how I intend to see it in the end, however.

Comment: If you only want it in the list of acronyms, you can just define as part of `foreign`? Currently, the output of `\ac{dsgvo}`is `Datenschutzgrundverordnung (“General Data Protection Regulation”, DSGVO)`. Do you want to change that as well?

Comment: @LokiRagnarok Well, that is a clever idea. And yes, would be great if both could be changed, but that one idea is already good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edited Answer, solution for v3 of `acro`

Since version 3 of `acro` you can add an acronym property:

```
\DeclareAcroProperty{foreign-short}
```

It can be used like any other property:

```
\DeclareAcronym{dsgvo}{
  short = DSGVO,
  long = {Datenschutz-Grundverordnung},
  foreign = General Data Protection Regulation ,
  foreign-short = GDPR, % new line
  foreign-babel = english,
  foreign-format = \enquote
}
```

Of course this doesn't suffice. In order to print the new property in the list you need to change the template for it (or create a new template altogether):

```
\RenewAcroTemplate[list]{description}{%
  \acroheading
  \acropreamble
  \begin{description}
    \acronymsmapF{
      \item [\acrowrite{short}\acroifT{alt}{/\acrowrite{alt}}]
        \acrowrite{long}%
        \acroifanyT{foreign,extra,foreign-short}{ (}%
        \acrowrite{foreign}%
        \acroifallT{foreign-short,foreign}{, }%
        \acrowrite{foreign-short}%
        \acroifanyT{foreign-short,foreign}{\acroifT{extra}{, }}%
        \acrowrite{extra}%
        \acroifanyT{foreign,extra,foreign-short}{)}%
        \acroifpagesT{%
          \acropagefill
          \acropages
            {\acrotranslate{page}\nobreakspace}%
            {\acrotranslate{pages}\nobreakspace}%
        }%
    }
    { \item \AcroRerun }
  \end {description}
}
```

If you also want to use it in the first/full form of the acronym you need to change the template for it, too:

```
\RenewAcroTemplate{long-short}{%
  \acroiffirstTF{%
    \acrowrite{long}\acspace
    (%
      \acrowrite{short}%
      \acroifT{foreign}{, }%
      \acrowrite{foreign}%
      \acroifT{foreign-short}{, }%
      \acrowrite{foreign-short}%
      \acrogroupcite
    )%
  }
  {\acrowrite{short}}%
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcroProperty{foreign-short}

\RenewAcroTemplate{long-short}{%
  \acroiffirstTF{%
    \acrowrite{long}\acspace
    (%
      \acrowrite{short}%
      \acroifT{foreign}{, }%
      \acrowrite{foreign}%
      \acroifT{foreign-short}{, }%
      \acrowrite{foreign-short}%
      \acrogroupcite
    )%
  }
  {\acrowrite{short}}%
}

\RenewAcroTemplate[list]{description}{%
  \acroheading
  \acropreamble
  \begin{description}
    \acronymsmapF{
      \item [\acrowrite{short}\acroifT{alt}{/\acrowrite{alt}}]
        \acrowrite{long}%
        \acroifanyT{foreign,extra,foreign-short}{ (}%
        \acrowrite{foreign}%
        \acroifallT{foreign-short,foreign}{, }%
        \acrowrite{foreign-short}%
        \acroifanyT{foreign-short,foreign}{\acroifT{extra}{, }}%
        \acrowrite{extra}%
        \acroifanyT{foreign,extra,foreign-short}{)}%
        \acroifpagesT{%
          \acropagefill
          \acropages
            {\acrotranslate{page}\nobreakspace}%
            {\acrotranslate{pages}\nobreakspace}%
        }%
    }
    { \item \AcroRerun }
  \end {description}
}

\DeclareAcronym{dsgvo}{
  short = DSGVO,
  long = {Datenschutz-Grundverordnung},
  foreign = General Data Protection Regulation ,
  foreign-short = GDPR, % new line
  foreign-babel = english,
  foreign-format = \enquote
}

\begin{document}

\ac{dsgvo}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Original Answer, solution for v2 of `acro`

You can use the `extra` property. With a little bit of styling the result comes near to what you want. An *exact* outcome would be more complicated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{
  foreign-format = \enquote ,
  list-foreign-format = \enquote ,
  % list-style = description , % default
  extra-style = paren ,
  page-style = comma ,
  pages = first
}

\DeclareAcroListStyle{description}{list}{
  foreign-sep = {, }
}

\shorthandon{"}

\DeclareAcronym{dsgvo}{
  short   = DSGVO,
  long    = {Datenschutz"=Grundverordnung} ,
  foreign = General Data Protection Regulation ,
  extra = GDPR ,
  foreign-lang = english
}

\begin{document}

\ac{dsgvo}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A real `foreign-short` property does not exist, yet. But to me it sounds like a reasonable feature request. Feel free to open it up at https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/new maybe with a reference to this question.

Comment: Done. [Reported as a suggestion/proposal there](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/136/support-foreign-short-for-listing-a-short).